# Losing of Notification Access permission after reboot

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-permissions

Some of my users report that my app lose Notification Access permissions (the check box that user should set manually) after phone reboot. I use this permission for my NotificationListenerService and it's critical for my app.
Did anyone had such problem? Any solutions?

**Update:**

The device is Samsung SM-N900 Galaxy Note 3 (offical ROM, no SD cards) powered by Android 5.0. What is interesting the user report that other app that have access to notification doesn't lose it on reboot. It makes me craisy. And I see that user absolutely correct, I see all this staf via internal log that he sent to me.

Comment: Interesting. Try to narrow this down to affected Android versions/devices.

Comment: This behavior is not common. Can you tell the details of test device along with the Android version?

Comment: I've just add some additional informatin in my post. Thanks for fast reply.

Comment: 2018, and the problem still exists in Samsung phones; Galaxy A7 2017, Nougat. Such a pain!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found that this is the problem of Samsung S4 firmware. All the apps (except system ones) lose this permission after phone reboot.

Hope Samsung will fix it in next update. Have no reports from other Samsung users.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue on an HTC One M9, Android 6.0 Marshmallow, stock ROM. I found the solution here:

https://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=70552218&postcount=49

Basically all I had to do was deleting the "Boost+" app. Now everything is fine (and the reboot is way faster... I really wonder what this app was really doing!).

Comment: No such app in my Samsung galaxy device. There are other '+' labelled system apps though but not 'boost+'.